# Manually aborting a job in a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

For the purpose of testing some code, I want to be able to simulate a batch job run and abort in the middle of execution. How can I do this from an apex test? I tried using a boolean flag to abort from within the job, but I when I check the AsyncApexJob table, it does not show that any job was aborted.

Can someone please provide me with any suggestions to do this? Thank you.